# Problema no login usando CakePhp no session_regenerate_id()

Tags: php, cakephp, header

Testando em casa, meu projeto CakePHP funciona perfeitamente. Porém ao executar o mesmo projeto no site, com as devidas alterações, como de esperado apresenta um comportamento um pouco diferente.

Mas um problema está realmente me incomodando ao tentar realizar o login:

```
Warning (2): Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
(output started at /local/local/local/site/app/Model/User.php:54)        
[CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 686]
Warning (2): session_regenerate_id() [function.session-regenerate-id]: Cannot regenerate s           
session id - headers already sent [CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/CakeSession.php, line 688]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está fazendo algum output de dados antes de enviar ou modificar os headers. Se você der uma olhada [neste artigo do stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php) eles explicam muito bem.

Da próxima vez que precisar de ajuda, coloca o trecho do código onde você acha que o erro está sendo gerado que fica mais fácil pra quem for responder.

Comment: coloquei um espaço depois da tag <?php ?> no model usado , e o model usado era acessado antes de alterar os items, obrigado